# the article before the noun "person"

Tags: grammar

*Me and you are very similar types of (a) person.*

I am not sure if the article before the noun "person" is necessary or can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

The article is not needed, but if you're interested in idiomatic speech, we wouldn't typically say "of person",  since it is implicit.

**You and I are similar types.

Me and you are similar types.** [ungrammatical but not uncommon].